# Need to rewrite .htaccess rule to redirect from Site A to Site B except the SITA index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect from Site A to site B all the URLs and subdomains except the index.php of site A. I used the below rules but none worked.

below is what i used to redirect all except the index

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^/index.php\
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Currently I m redirecting everything from site A to site B by using code which is working fine with below rule

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

how can i rewrite it in such a way that site A's index.php open the same as it is and everything else from site A redirects to site B.

I tried with the one it still doesnt work. everything is going to site b. And index,php of site A is the same i.e [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) I want this to open as it is. But [www.abc.com/anything](http://www.abc.com/anything) to the site B

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with below rule, I made an exception in your current rule to ignore only index.php and accept every other matches.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your previous attempt regardless matching everything.

Comment: I think its the same as the second rule i have written. What change you introduced please let me know maybe I missed something? Anyways I used this too but its redirecting my index to the new site as well.

Comment: @pankajkarkra your previous rule should be written like this https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=abc5da91-8fd0-4b26-a70a-73f2c9fba818

Comment: I tried with the one it still doesnt work. everything is going to site b. And index,php of site A is the same i.e www.abc.com I want this to open as it is. But www.abc.com/anything to the site B

Comment: `
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$
  RewriteRule (.+) http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
`
This works for me 
Thanks